# How to dump local MySQL data to remote MySQL server through terminal?

Tags: shell, terminal, mysql

I'm currently working on some local development, which often need to update the remote database with my own local development database.

This is what I try to do, dump the local database and ssh to remote and update the db.

```
mysqldump -ulocaluser -plocalpass localdb | ssh user@255.255.255.255 "mysql -uremoteuser -premotepass remotedb"
```

It seem like completed without any error, but checking on the remote db, it seem like the old table never drop and replace with the new table data, any one can tell me what's wrong this?

Answer (score 1):

Check the output of `mysqldump -ulocaluser -plocalpass localdb` Does this contain `drop` statements?

Comment: yup it included 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS'